# Adding new Gender Profile Info in Wowonder

Tags: php

im using a Wowonder script Social network and i want to add Unspecified gender in my profile settings but it shows error on my page.

```
<?php 
$gender = ucfirst(strtolower($wo['user_profile']['gender'])); echo ($gender == 'Male') ? $wo['lang']['male'] : $wo['lang']['female'] : $wo['lang']['unspecified'];
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: `echo ($gender == 'Male') ? $wo['lang']['male'] : (($gender == 'Female') ? $wo['lang']['female'] : $wo['lang']['unspecified']);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I post it as a answer:

```
echo ($gender == 'Male') ? $wo['lang']['male'] : (($gender == 'Female') ? $wo['lang']['female'] : $wo['lang']['unspecified']);
```

Comment: hello when im going to add another gender seems it didnt work this is the code
echo ($gender == 'Male') ? $wo['lang']['male'] : ($gender == 'Female') ? $wo['lang']['female'] : (($gender == 'Dragon') ? $wo['lang']['dragon'] : $wo['lang']['princess']);

Comment: `echo ($gender == 'Male') ? $wo['lang']['male'] : (($gender == 'Female') ? $wo['lang']['female'] : (($gender == 'Dragon') ? $wo['lang']['dragon'] : $wo['lang']['princess']))`